# rename layers stacked in histogram (rasterVis)

Tags: r, plot, histogram, rastervis

I have the following problem, I failed to rename the layer stack.

Here an example of my code.

```
###
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
oo<-stack(r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r)
names(oo) <- as.character(2000:2015)
names(oo)
histogram(oo,na.rm=T,col="blue",
          panel = function(x, ...) {
          panel.histogram(x, ...)
          panel.mathdensity(dmath = dnorm, col = "red",
                   args = list(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)),lwd=2.5)
})
###
```

if use only numbers

```
names(oo) <- as.character(2000:2015)
```

result:
    names(oo)

```
[1] "X2000" "X2001" "X2002" "X2003" "X2004" "X2005" "X2006" "X2007" "X2008"
[10] "X2009" "X2010" "X2011" "X2012" "X2013" "x2014" "X2015"
```

as seen in the image:

[image: output]
but I need without the "X" i.e:

```
[1] "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" "2006" "2007" "2008"
[10] "2009" "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015"
```

apparently does not work with numbers, because if I try with:

```
names(oo) <- paste0("hola",1:16)
names(oo)

[1] "hola1"  "hola2"  "hola3"  "hola4"  "hola5"  "hola6"  "hola7"  "hola8" 
[9] "hola9"  "hola10" "hola11" "hola12" "hola13" "hola14" "hola15" "hola16"
```

the result it's ok in the plot.

PD: Also try with the parameter:

```
names.attr=as.character(2000,2015)
```

all suggestions are welcome please.

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

The `names.attr` argument is not implemented in the `histogram` function (yet). Instead, you have to use the `strip` argument provided by the original `lattice::histogram` function:

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)

oo <- stack(replicate(8, r))
nms <- as.character(2000:2015)

histogram(oo, na.rm = T, col = "blue",
          strip = strip.custom(factor.levels = nms),
          panel = function(x, ...) {
                  panel.histogram(x, ...)
                  panel.mathdensity(dmath = dnorm, col = "red",
                                    args = list(mean=mean(x),
                                               sd=sd(x)),
                                    lwd=2.5)
          })
```

Comment: Solved. 
Thank you very much Dr. @oscar-perpiñán.